# A short question about Hall $\pi$ subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

Let $\pi$ be a set of primes. Our definition for Hall $\pi$-subgroups states: A Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$  is a subgroup $H$ where $|H|$ is product of elements of $\pi$ and $|G:H|$ is product of $P\setminus\pi$ where $P$ is the set of all primes. So basically $|H|$ and $|G:H|$ are coprime.

My script says, that a solvable group G always has a Hall $\pi$-subgroup for any $\pi$. I think I'm missing something here, because I don't understand how this works for example for $S_4$ and $\pi = \{5\}$. How is there a subgroup of $S_4$ that is a product of elements of $\pi$ to begin with?

Comment: I find this definition annoying. In the case you mention you have to choose the empty product (order $1$). A better to understand formulation : "If $G$ is a solvable group and its order is $n$, then there is a sub-group of order $m$, whenever $m$ and $\frac{n}{m}$ (the order of the index) are coprime integers".

Comment: No, the Hall 5-subgroup is trivial.

Comment: You want to use `\setminus` for the set difference operator. So `P\setminus\pi` to get $P\setminus\pi$, instead of $P/\pi$.

Comment: The empty product equals $1$, and all prime factors of that product are in $\{5\}$. This is the equivalent of saying every finite group has Sylow $p$-subgroups for every $p$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I think you mean the trivial subgroup...

Comment: Yes perhaps I do. Or perhaps I meant the Hall $\pi'$-subgroup?